# Run same javascript independent from each other

Tags: javascript

Working on the following demo, I have got a problem about making the code work twice (or more times).

I just wanted to add more "before/after" images, but seems like the draggable bar only works on the main one, and applies the movement to the others.

Is there any solution to make it work independent from each one?

Where could be the error:

```
$(function(){
  var $dragMe               = $("#dragme");
  var $beforeAfter      = $("#before-after");
  var $viewAfter          = $(".view-after");

  Draggable.create($dragMe, {
      type:"left",
      bounds: $beforeAfter,
      onDrag:updateImages
  });
```

**DEMO:** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JHVH5/)

Comment: What Batu Zet said is correct, please note that having the same ID in the same html page is NOT valid html.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JHVH5/1/

Comment: Sorry for my first comment i havent seen the line correctly when you said _work independent from each one_. That case you just need to make those buttons seperately for every each of them and give your divs unique ids and create draggable for those ids seperately.

Comment: My mistake! I just found out I missed to change the #dragme class on css, so that's why I suposed it was a Javascript problem since modifying it on the HTML & Javascript didnt work. Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: It's not very typical to prefix JavaScript variable names with `$`. I would recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

As answered on my previous post by @Jonas Grumman, here goes the solution:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JHVH5/1)

The main problem was on executing two ID tags on the same html page.

Otherwhise was my mistake since I forgot to change it on css, so focusing only on html & javascript was an error.

So modifying the following parts, was enough:

HTML (before):

```
<div id="dragme"></div>
```

HTML (after):

```
<div class="dragme"></div>
```

Javascript (before):

```
var $dragMe  = $("#dragme");
```

Javascript (after):

```
var $dragMe  = $(".dragme");
```

CSS (before):

```
#dragme{
        some css styles here
        }
```

CSS (after):

```
.dragme{
        some css styles here
        }
```